# How to prevent showing logged in user in member list?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have admin list and member list which i have categorize by 'a' and 'm'. Now i am showing admin lists and member lists in different tabs. Now problem is if a user is in member list and is logged in than his name should not shown in member list.

Here is the controller:

```
public function view_customer(){
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    $customers=$this->um->view_customers();
     header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
     echo json_encode($customers);
}
```

Here is the model:

```
    public function view_customers(){
    $this->db->select('reg_id,reg_name,email,user_type,pic_url,id,name,cover_image,restaurant_id');
    $this->db->from('registration');
    $this->db->where('user_type','m');
$this->db->join('rest_restaurant_master','registration.restaurant_id=rest_restaurant_master.id','inner');
    $query=$this->db->get()->result_array();
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: You're saying that if a member is logged in and has a `user_type` of `'m'` that they should not be displayed in the member list?

Comment: @commanderZiltoid yes.

Comment: Are you wanting the logged in member to not see their name, but anyone else who can view the list can see their name? If this is what you are after, when rendering the results in your view I would check that the id of the member record is not equal to the id of the authenticated user. If this isn't what you are after, could you provide a bit more detail?

Comment: Yes i want i can't see my name but other can see my name under member list.

Comment: It's not all that strange. I mean a user typically has a separate page where they can edit their own stuff; no real need to have them in a list if they know their there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need a variable that is both contained in your table, and is related to the user. I'm assuming you have one called `id` that relates to a session variable called `user_id`.

Add to `view_customers`:

```
$this->db->where_not_in('id', $this->session->user_id);
```

Or (easier):

```
$this->db->where('id !=', $this->session->user_id);
```

This way your array will contain users who are only in `m` and who are not the **active** user.

Comment: Your answer seems the solution of my problem. But i have not used sessions before. So i will try to implement sessions in user table and get id in view_customers method.

Comment: If you aren't using sessions how do you know if the user is logged in? If you are using something else (don't know what) just replace the session in the code with whatever user identifiable variable you have.

Comment: If you are just implementing logins I would suggest using the Ion Auth library for ci. It's very robust and simple, just requires some gui on your part.

Comment: Alright i will try to implement sessions in login api. If i will required help i will ping you again.

Comment: Hello again. I have written this thing in login controller: $sess_array = array(
             'id' => $row->id,
             'reg_name' => $row->reg_name,
             'email' => $row->email
           );
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);                                and now shall i have to call session in view_customer controller or directly used this " $this->db->where_not_in('id', $this->session->user_id);" in " view_customers" model under where condition?

Comment: In your registration table is the field ID equivalent to the user ID? Or is it just a unrelated key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159466/discussion-between-nauman-malik-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

When you set session (in login)

```
$newdata = array(
    'id'        => 3, # id is database user recorded id
    'username'  => 'johndoe',
    'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
    'logged_in' => TRUE
);

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

and then in all the method you can call

```
$loggedUser = $this->session->id; # or $this->session->userdata('id');

$this->db->where_not_in('id', $loggedUser);
```

[Read this Session Library class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)